# Update portions of data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do a data update using Oracle.

I have a situation where I have data/records that may look like this:

Table Name: IPDATA

Column Name with these records is called: info

```
Web Proxy (abc):ZZZ Gateway gen1:gen2  
ZZZ Gateway gen1:gen2:Web Proxy (abc)  
ZZZ Gateway gen1:gen2  
Web Proxy (abc):ZZZ Gateway gen1:gen2:XYZ Systems  
Web Proxy (abc):ZZZ Gateway gen1:gen2:XYZ Systems:POP SetUp  
Web Proxy (abc):XYZ Systems:POP SetUp:ZZZ Gateway gen1:gen2
```

What I need to do is find records that have the string "ZZZ Gateway gen1:gen2" - just these that exist within records and replace just this ":" with a ", " ONLY

End result would then be:

```
Web Proxy (abc):ZZZ Gateway gen1, gen2  
ZZZ Gateway gen1, gen2:Web Proxy (abc)  
ZZZ Gateway gen1, gen2  
Web Proxy (abc):ZZZ Gateway gen1, gen2:XYZ Systems  
Web Proxy (abc):ZZZ Gateway gen1, gen2:XYZ Systems:POP SetUp  
Web Proxy (abc):XYZ Systems:POP SetUp:ZZZ Gateway gen1, gen2
```

I have tried it using updates with substr and replace but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you could get away with replacing "1:" with "1,"

```
update IPDATA 
set info=replace(info, '1:', '1,' )  
where info like('%ZZZ Gateway gen1:gen2%')
```

Comment: thanks but are there any other ways of possibly doing it aside from this approach?

Comment: Is there some way in which this approach is defficient?

Comment: not at all stimms - just wondering if there possibly was another means. thanks.